# Reading text from image, facing problem because of the font

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image]

I am trying to read this image and do the arithmetic operation in the image. For some reason i am not able to read 7 because of the font it has. I am relatively new to image processing. Can you please help me with solution. I tried pixeliating the image, but that did not help.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('modules/visual_basic_math/temp2.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 6'))
```

Response i am getting is -

```
+44 849559
+46653% 14
+7776197
+6415995
+*9156346
x4463310
+54Q%433
+1664 20%
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, tesseract is a bit outdated. There are much more powerful libraries. I recommend PaddleOCR. To install it:

- `pip install paddlepaddle`
- `pip install paddleocr`

Then:

```py
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR

ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='es')
predictions = ocr.ocr("ietDJ.png")[0]

filtered_text = []
for pred in predictions:
    filtered_text.append(pred[-1][0])

filtered_text = [t.replace(" ", "") for t in filtered_text] # Remove spaces
```

```bash
['+4487559', '+4665714', '+7776157', ':6415995', ':9156346', 'x4463310', '-54q7433', '+1664207']
```

The output is not completely correct (the division symbols are : and one of them is wrong). Also, it confuses a 9 with a q. However, the results are better and the use of the library is as comfortable as tesseract.

Hope it helps!